# git access for www-data via ssh to bitbucket

Tags: git, ssh, permissions, bitbucket

I am try to pull/clone git project from bitbucket with user **www-data**. The Deployment keys was created and added to Access keys of bitbucket. The server response that I *have read access* but when I try pull or clone - *access denied*.

```
www-data@server:~$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:project/repo.git
Cloning into 'repo'...
repository access denied. deployment key is not associated with the requested repository.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
www-data@server:~$ ssh -T  git@bitbucket.org
authenticated via a deploy key.


You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.

This deploy key has read access to the following repositories:

project/repo: wwwdata2 -- www-data@server
```

Comment: The two `project/repo`s above, one where you `git clone` and the other where Bitbucket tells you the repositories the key can access, are identical?

Comment: The same, access keys from this repository.

Answer (score 0):

Access keys are associated with one or more specific repos, not with a project or user. If you're getting this message, then you'll need to add that access key to the repo(s) that need it.

Comment: Access keys added only to this repository.